# Webpack with ES6 presets not understanding ES6 syntax

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have a very basic project going for React with Webpack enabled ES6. This is what my Webpack config file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333,
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I have some React code with a component declared using `class` and that component has some arrow functions in it. When I run the page, the Webpack dev server shows the following error:

```
ERROR in ./App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Alex/src/todo/App.js: Unexpected token (23:12)
  21 |  };
  22 |
> 23 |  handleOpen = () => {
     |             ^
  24 |          this.setState({open: true});
  25 |  };
  26 |
```

It seems that from reading on the Babel website, the preset `'es2015'` ought to be enough. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is a part of [ES Class Fields & Static Properties proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties), which is still in stage-1 as of writing this, so you have to add [preset-stage-1](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/) in order to use it.

If you use stage-0, it will also work.

Alterantively, you could use just the [`transform-class-properties` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: That worked, thank you! But I don't understand; when I look at [this page for the ES2015 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/), arrow functions is on there. What am I missing?

Comment: I just submitted updated the answer few seconds after you upvoted/commented, I think this should explain what's going on. It's not the simple arrow function, but a class properly that is compiled differently. Or you can check the [Instance Field Declaration Process](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties#instance-field-declaration-process).